# Django admin list view customizable by user

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to make list view columns to be customizable by user. I ask for something ready to use (if there are not something similar, i will write something mine).

Comment: are you talking about `list_display` ?

Comment: No. list_display is not customizable by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your admin.py you can do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age') # column to display
```

more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

So `diango-xadmin` is the final answer.

Comment: Noup. I know about list_display. list_display is NOT customizable by user. I want dynamic list_display (If i have model with columnt First Name, Second Name, Family Name, Age, City, Country for example, i want user make choice what column want to see...one user may choice First Name, Family Name, Age, but another user may want to see only Family Name and City for example.)

Comment: Thanks. This is something useful.

Comment: When you login `http://demo.xadmin.io/` and select some table, then the `column` button on the right is want you want.